# django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage. Ошибка при выполнении python3 manage.py collectstatic

Tags: django

Ошибка при выполнении `collectstatic`:

> django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage не находит файл 'fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'

Та же ошибка при использовании `whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage`

Мои настройки статики

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ui')
STATIC_BASE = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'ui')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('application', os.path.join(STATIC_BASE, 'application', 'build')),
    ('images', os.path.join(STATIC_BASE, 'application', 'images'))
)
```

Консоль

```
user@user-desktop:~/PycharmProjects/blabla$ python3 manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/user/PycharmProjects/blabla/ui

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Post-processed 'admin/css/forms.css' as 'admin/css/forms.70b858e61281.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/rtl.css' as 'admin/css/rtl.e024aaf6df25.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/login.css' as 'admin/css/login.a846c0e2ef65.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/fonts.css' as 'admin/css/fonts.cc6140298ba7.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/changelists.css' as 'admin/css/changelists.32a12db9a480.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/widgets.css' as 'admin/css/widgets.a7251c097987.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/base.css' as 'admin/css/base.9f6547179ace.css'
Post-processed 'admin/css/dashboard.css' as 'admin/css/dashboard.4898e2e9983d.css'
Post-processing 'application/application.css' failed!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 128, in collect
    raise processed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 245, in post_process
    content = pattern.sub(converter, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 184, in converter
    hashed_url = self.url(unquote(joined_result), force=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 131, in url
    hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 280, in stored_name
    cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
    (clean_name, self))
ValueError: The file 'fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' could not be found with <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7faf4fb40320>.
```

*grunt* собирает все css файлы в *application.css*.

В *bootstrap.css* файле прописаны эти пути к файлам, которые не находятся:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Папка со шрифтами должна находится относительно css файла по указанному пути: `../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`

В моем случае я сделал так:
Создал папку: ui/application/fonts/bootstrap/ 
Указал поиск статики в этой папке:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('application', os.path.join(STATIC_BASE, 'application', 'build')),
    ('images', os.path.join(STATIC_BASE, 'application', 'images')),
    ('fonts', os.path.join(STATIC_BASE, 'application', 'fonts'))
)
```

Перенес в нее шрифты из папки: bower_components/bootstrap/fonts

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]